# OpenCV Camera to Object Horizontal Angle Calculation

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

So, I'm a high school student and the lead programmer on my local robotics team, and this year I decided to try out OpenCV and do some vision processing on our robot.

From my vision code, I need to know a few things about some objects on our competition field. These things are: distance (ft), horizontal angle from camera, and horizontal distance from camera (ft). Essentially, one large right triangle.

I already have the camera successfully detecting these objects and putting a boundingRect around them. With a gyroscope on our robot, we should be able to get our robot to ~90 degree angle to the object once it is detected (as it's a set angle on the field). Thus, I can calculate distance just based on an empirically made function of the area of the boundingRect of the object.

The horizontal angle of the object from the camera, however, I'm not exactly sure how to approach. Once I have that, though, I can do some simple trig and get the horizontal distance.

-

So here's what we have/know: Distance to object in ft, object is at ~90 degrees to camera, camera has horizontal fov of 67 degrees w/ resolution of 800x600, the real world dimensions of the object, and a boundingRect around the object.

How would I, using all of this information, calculate the horizontal angle from the camera to the object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compute horizontal angle of a pixel from a computer vision camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524787/how-to-compute-horizontal-angle-of-a-pixel-from-a-computer-vision-camera)