# Point cloud conversion to 2D range

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-clouds, kinect-v2

I am trying to convert a point cloud (x, y, z) data acquired from a Kinect V2 using [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2), into a *virtual* 2D laser scan (e.g., a horizontal angle/distance vector).

I am currently assigning per pixel column, the PCL distance value, as shown below:

```
std::vector<float> scan(512, 0);
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 424; ++row) {
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < 512; ++col) {
        float x, y, z;
        registration->getPointXYZ(depth, row, col, x, y, z);
        if (std::isnan(x) || std::isnan(y) || std::isnan(z)) {
            continue;
        }
        Eigen::Vector3f values = rotate_translate((-1 * x), y - 1.186, z);
        if (scan[col] == 0) {
            scan[col] = values[1];
        }
        if (values[1] < scan[col]) {
            scan[col] = values[1];
        }
    }
}
```

You may ignore the `rotate_translate` method, it simply changes the local to global coordinates using the sensor pose.

The problem is best shown using the pictures below:

Whereas the LIDAR range sensor produces the following pointsmap:

[image: lidar Map]

the kinect 2D range scan is **curved**, and of course narrower, since the horizontal FOV is 70.6 degrees compared to the 270 degree range of the LIDAR.

[image: kinect map]

It is this curvature that I am trying to fix; the SLAM/ICP library I'm using is [mrpt](http://www.mrpt.org/) and the actual data `scan` is inserted into an `mrpt::obs::CObservation2DRangeScan` observation:

```
auto obs = mrpt::obs::CObservation2DRangeScan();
obs.loadFromVectors(scan.size(), scan.data(), (char*)scan.data());
obs.aperture = mrpt::utils::DEG2RAD(70.6f);
obs.maxRange = 6.0;
obs.rightToLeft = true;
obs.timestamp = mrpt::system::now();
obs.setSensorPose(sensor);
```

I've searched around google and SO, and the only answers which seem to address this question, are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530762/499699) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499538/499699). So whereas I understand that the curvature is the result of me assigning each pixel column the PCL value, I am uncertain as to how I can use that to remove the curvature.

Each reply seems to take a different approach, and from what I understand the task is a *linear interpolation* of the angle per pixel ratio, and the current pixel coordinates?