# How to correct camera mounting error through camera calibration?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am developing a machine vision system to drive a PNP machine. Rather than fabricating a PCB, this machine only pick and paste a panel on our product. Using openpnp to drive this machine is overkill and irrelevent. But I love the auto vision calibration function, especially it can correct the camera mounting error.

[openpnp auto camera calibration capability](https://github.com/openpnp/openpnp/wiki/Advanced-Camera-Calibration)

[camera mounting error illustrated](https://github.com/openpnp/openpnp/wiki/Advance-Camera-Calibration---Camera-Mounting-Errors#camera-mounting-errors)

[openpnp auto calibration in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md68n_J7uto)

I known by calibrating the camera using chessboard, only can find the extrinsic parameters that is not directly related to camera tilt mounting error and Z Axis mounting error

I want to do this in C++ or python opencv, but I can not find the relevent source of openpnp on test branch. I wise someone could elaborate this auto calibration algorithm, or pointing me the right location of openpnp source code, or recommend another opensource project which can do this

Comment: found another more detail calibration scenarios, each scenario iterate 32 times to collect 32 pictures on radical direction in random order

[buttom camera auto calibration in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsFHtk0lFuk)
,

[top camera auto calibration in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rq5FHjePp8g)

Comment: I found this is more related to what I want,
[OpenCV: Calculate Angle between camera and object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080775/opencv-calculate-angle-between-camera-and-object)

Comment: I just find the openpnp advance calibration source code, [advance calibration](https://github.com/openpnp/openpnp/blob/460d8aa4bbfa2a59af1afd2c6e03487d4ba63406/src/main/java/org/openpnp/machine/reference/camera/calibration/AdvancedCalibration.java#L51)

Comment: when all the angles and translation were ready, to compute an virtual perfect mounted camera's view is easy, [virtual camera rotating/translating for bird's eye view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606891/opencv-virtually-camera-rotating-translating-for-birds-eye-view)

Comment: a more dig into camera calibration topic, I found visp project is digging more deep, [Camera intrinsic calibration](https://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-3.5.0/tutorial-calibration-intrinsic.html)

![Camera intrinsic derived camera position](https://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-3.5.0/img-calib-script-extrinsic.jpg).